# Apache 2.4.6 mod_proxy_fcgi and PHP-FPM returning 404 error

Tags: apache, apache2, php, mod-proxy

I have PHP 5.3.3 with PHP-FPM running at 172.17.0.163:20533. I tested it with nginx and with cgi-fcgi:

```
$ SCRIPT_FILENAME=/www/localhost/test.php REQUEST_METHOD=GET cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 172.17.0.163:20533
```

returns

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Content-type: text/html

hello, it works!
```

So, PHP-FPM is working.

**Unfortunately, Apache 2.4 has some issues with PHP-FPM:**

```
<VirtualHost *>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/%0"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://172.17.0.163:20533/www/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

Opening http:// localhost/test.php returns a "404 Not found" error. Non PHP files are working. Looking at the apache error logs, everything looks fine.

```
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:00.426776 2013] [mpm_event:info] [pid 1959:tid 140474380953408] AH00490: Server built: Nov 13 2013 14:23:31
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:00.426787 2013] [core:notice] [pid 1959:tid 140474380953408] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/sbin/httpd'
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:00.426917 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3028:tid 140474380953408] proxy_util.c(1694): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:00.426950 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3028:tid 140474380953408] proxy_util.c(1734): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:00.427010 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3028:tid 140474380953408] proxy_util.c(1769): AH00930: initialized pool in child 3028 for (*) min=0 max=25 smax=25
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:00.427101 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3030:tid 140474380953408] proxy_util.c(1694): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:00.427421 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3029:tid 140474380953408] proxy_util.c(1694): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:00.427445 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3029:tid 140474380953408] proxy_util.c(1734): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:00.427488 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3029:tid 140474380953408] proxy_util.c(1769): AH00930: initialized pool in child 3029 for (*) min=0 max=25 smax=25
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:00.427129 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3030:tid 140474380953408] proxy_util.c(1734): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:00.428326 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3030:tid 140474380953408] proxy_util.c(1769): AH00930: initialized pool in child 3030 for (*) min=0 max=25 smax=25
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.627599 2013] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] 172.17.42.1 - - [localhost/sid#7fc2bd82e7f8][rid#7fc2bd7a10a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /test.php
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.627664 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] 172.17.42.1 - - [localhost/sid#7fc2bd82e7f8][rid#7fc2bd7a10a0/initial] applying pattern '^/(.*\\.php(/.*)?)$' to uri '/test.php'
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.627718 2013] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] 172.17.42.1 - - [localhost/sid#7fc2bd82e7f8][rid#7fc2bd7a10a0/initial] rewrite '/test.php' -> 'fcgi://172.17.0.163:20533/www/localhost/test.php'
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.627747 2013] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] 172.17.42.1 - - [localhost/sid#7fc2bd82e7f8][rid#7fc2bd7a10a0/initial] forcing proxy-throughput with fcgi://172.17.0.163:20533/www/localhost/test.php
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.627759 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] 172.17.42.1 - - [localhost/sid#7fc2bd82e7f8][rid#7fc2bd7a10a0/initial] go-ahead with proxy request proxy:fcgi://172.17.0.163:20533/www/localhost/test.php [OK]
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.627776 2013] [proxy_fcgi:trace1] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(90): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] canonicalising URL //172.17.0.163:20533/www/localhost/test.php
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.627776 2013] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(120): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] AH01060: set r->filename to proxy:fcgi://172.17.0.163:20533/www/localhost/test.php
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.628070 2013] [proxy:trace2] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] proxy_util.c(1857): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] *: found reverse proxy worker for fcgi://172.17.0.163:20533/www/localhost/test.php
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.628082 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] mod_proxy.c(1100): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] AH01143: Running scheme fcgi handler (attempt 0)
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.628096 2013] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(944): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] AH01076: url: fcgi://172.17.0.163:20533/www/localhost/test.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.628107 2013] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(954): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] AH01078: serving URL //172.17.0.163:20533/www/localhost/test.php
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.628134 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] proxy_util.c(2020): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.628147 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] proxy_util.c(2072): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] AH00944: connecting //172.17.0.163:20533/www/localhost/test.php to 172.17.0.163:20533
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.628224 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] proxy_util.c(2194): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] AH00947: connected /www/localhost/test.php to 172.17.0.163:20533
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.628248 2013] [proxy:trace2] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] proxy_util.c(2446): FCGI: fam 2 socket created to connect to *
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.629453 2013] [proxy_fcgi:trace4] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] util_script.c(521): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] Headers from script 'test.php':
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.629552 2013] [proxy_fcgi:trace4] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] util_script.c(522): [client 172.17.42.1:57951]   Status: 404 Not Found
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.629583 2013] [proxy_fcgi:trace1] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] util_script.c(599): [client 172.17.42.1:57951] Status line from script 'test.php': 404 Not Found
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.629595 2013] [proxy_fcgi:trace4] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] util_script.c(522): [client 172.17.42.1:57951]   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.629608 2013] [proxy_fcgi:trace4] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] util_script.c(522): [client 172.17.42.1:57951]   Content-type: text/html
[Fri Nov 15 18:53:01.629680 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 3028:tid 140474150618880] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
```

It seems as if mod_proxy_fcgi is not sending the script path correctly?! Has anyone an idea?

**UPDATE 16 Nov 2013**

I tested it with Apache 2.2.25 and mod_fastcgi 2.4.6:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/%0"

    AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
    FastCgiExternalServer /www/localhost -host 172.17.0.163:20533
</VirtualHost>
```

Works like a charm. I guess Apache 2.4.6 with mod_proxy_fcgi is buggy.

**Update 17 Nov 2013**

I tested it with Apache 2.4.6 and mod_proxy_fcgi and PHP 5.4.21. It works. So, there seems to be a problem with PHP 5.3.3 together with Apache 2.4.6 and mod_proxy_fcgi.

Comment: Maybe I found more details about this issue: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51517

Comment: I do not use mod_proxy / FPM TCP setup, but I do use mod_fastcgi / socket with Apache 2.4.x and perhaps you'll find something useful here -> https://gist.github.com/diemuzi/3849349 it's helped a few others get started at least. I know this setup works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP 5.3.27 fixes all the issues.